# Receiving notifications: on click handle for multiple activities

Tags: java, android, notifications

In my application, I have two main activities:

MainActivity and MessagesActivity

When the notification is clicked and the application is not running, I want it to start the MainActivity.  However, when the application is running and the MessagesActivity is in view, I want when the user clicks the notification to somehow receive the intent data.

I create my notification something like this:

```
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(MESSAGE_KEY, receivedMessage);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(MESSAGE_ID_KEY, receivedMessageId);
        int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT, intent.getExtras());

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                ....build();
        notificationManager.notify(requestID, notification);
```

I've tried playing around with other flags, launchModes, etc.  This wouldn't be a problem if it was all just one activity but onNewIntent is never called when the application is running in either MainActivity or MessagesActivity

Comment: Hi vincentjames501, I need to do the same thing now. Is that possible? Can you solve this?